# Create multiple user access with different tables or datatabse

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to allow each user to have his own login credential and access his own database or table but within a single cluster created by me in mongodb.

Comment: MongoDB provides [authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/index.html#authentication) and [role-base access control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/#role-based-access-control), does that not work for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Simply switch to the admin database and create a user with built-in role readWrite for the specific database for that user.  For example, if you have a user "billy" who should have access to database "billydb" only...

```
use admin
db.createUser({user: "billy", pwd: "billypassword", roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: "billydb" }]})
```

This assumes your MongoDB start up configuration includes authorization.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security-options